# sql create column based on other columns with existing values

Tags: sql, t-sql

I need some t-sql help to create the column 'Grp' in the below table. Basicaly i need to create a column that states when a value exists, if it's null then exclude it from the 'Grp' column. The table is an example of my end result required (only Col1,Col2,Col3 exists now)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a few `CASE` expressions with a `STUFF` to remove leading `-`.

```
SELECT
    STUFF(
        (
            CASE WHEN T.Col1 IS NOT NULL THEN '-Col1' ELSE '' END +
            CASE WHEN T.Col2 IS NOT NULL THEN '-Col2' ELSE '' END +
            CASE WHEN T.Col3 IS NOT NULL THEN '-Col3' ELSE '' END 
        ),
        1, 1, ''),
    T.Col1,
    T.Col2,
    T.Col3
FROM
    YourTable AS T
```

Comment: Case _expressions_.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a case when statement:

```
select 
  left(t.Grp,len(Grp)-1) as Grp,
  t.col1,t.col2,t.col3
from (    
  select col1, col2, col3,
    case when col1 is null then '' else 'col1-' +
    case when col2 is null then '' else 'col2-' +
    case when col3 is null then '' else 'col3-'
    as Grp
  from your_table
  ) t
```

Comment: fix your case statement it contain multiple else

Comment: Case _expression_.